# Two Poisson r.vs with different rates may have same value at some argument

Tags: probability-distributions, transcendental-equations

I am curious whether two Poisson distributions with two different rate parameters may have the same probability value at some positive integer argument i-e I am trying to solve

$$\frac{e^{-\lambda _0} \lambda _0^x}{x!} \overset{?}{=} \frac{e^{-\lambda _1} \lambda _1^x}{x!}  \quad \quad \text{where $ \: x \in \mathbb {Z}^+$ and $\lambda_0 \neq \lambda_1.$} $$

I did try to start with numerical methods but didn't reach any where. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: For every $x\geqslant1$ and every $\lambda_0$ in $(0,x)$ there exists a unique $\lambda_1$ in $(x,+\infty)$ such that this holds. Furthermore, $\lambda_1$ can be written down in terms of $\lambda_0$ and of the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), yielding an explicit and useless formula. Is this your question?

Comment: Perhaps Yes. This was my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n$. Its derivative is $e^{-\lambda}(n\lambda^{n-1}-\lambda^n)$, or equivalently $e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{n-1}(n-\lambda)$.

Take for example $n=1$. Then $f(\lambda)$ is increasing until $\lambda=1$, and then decreasing. So there are infinitely many pairs $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1)$ with $\lambda_0\lt 1$ and $\lambda_1\gt 1$ at which we have equality. A similar result holds for any other positive $n$.